# Load data before angular bootstrapping and passing it to a service

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to check if the user is logged in (some tokens saved locally) by making a http request to the server.

I have another security service used to do all stuff regarding authentication.

```
(function() {
    var myApp = angular.module("app");

    fetchData().then(bootstrapApplication);

    function fetchData() {
        var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
        var $http = initInjector.get("$http");

        //makes a request to currentUser using token from $localStorage
        var localData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('authorizationData'));
        //if token exists in localStorage it adds a provider 
        if (localData && localData.token) {
          //adds the header
          $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localData.token;
          //makes call
        } 
        return $http.get("http://demo-site/current-user")
          .then(function(response) {
            // successfull, adds currentUser as a constant

            angular.module('security').config(['authServiceProvider', function (authServiceProvider) {
              authService().authenticate(response.data)
            }]);

          }, function(errorResponse) {
              // Handle error case
          });
    }

    function bootstrapApplication() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
        });
    }
}());
```

and the security service looks like this:

```
angular.module('security', ['ngNewRouter'])
    // .factory('authService',  authService);
    .service('authService', ['$http', '$q', '$window', 'CONSTANTS', '$location', '$router', authService ]);


function authService($http, $q, $window, CONSTANTS, $location, $router) {
    var service = {};
    var r = $router;


    //successfull data either from login or currentUser
    var _authenticate = function(data) {
        if (is('String', data.token)) {
            var lsData = {
                shopId: data.response.id,
                token: data.token
            }
            $window.localStorage.setItem('authorizationData', JSON.stringify(lsData));
        }
        if (is('Object', data.response) && data.response.id)
            service.currentUser = data.response;
    }

... 
service.authenticate = _authenticate;
return service;
}
```

The authenticate method is called when user logged in with success. (first login also returns token to be saved locally, after that only sets currentUser inside the authService.

How would I make it possible to set currentUser after receiving http response before bootstrap and to keep it inside the app?

That's the part I wrote, on request success:

```
angular.module('security').config(['authServiceProvider', function (authServiceProvider) {
                  authService().authenticate(response.data)
                }]);
```

Comment: seems similar, but how do I pass data to the service?

Comment: In the other answer the data is injected into a controller - the same way it could be injected into a service